# solaris md5 files in all subdirectories

Tags: find, md5, solaris

I need to search all duplicated files in folder and subdirectories of this folder. how use find and md5 to get list for all files?

find ./ -type f -name '*' -exec md5sum {} > checksums.txt \;

above comand doesnt work

or is it possible to remove the 'newer one'?

thx in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite the checksums.txt during the find with each file found.
The -name '*'does not add anything to the query, so you could enter

```
find . -type f -exec md5sum {} \; > checksums.txt
```

Or use append (>>).